# Flutter GoogleMobileAds fluid height

Tags: flutter, admob, google-mobile-ads

I am looking to implement Google Admanager **native** and normal banners in my app and cannot figure out a way to get the height to adapt to the different banners, without having to specify it beforehand.

This is my current code:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';

class NativeAdBanner extends HookWidget {
  const NativeAdBanner({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bannerAd = useState<NativeAd?>(null);
    final bannerAdIsLoaded = useState<bool>(false);

    // load the banner ad
    useEffect(
      () {
        bannerAd.value = NativeAd(
          adUnitId: Platform.isAndroid
              ? 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110'
              : 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716',
          nativeTemplateStyle: NativeTemplateStyle(
            templateType: TemplateType.medium,
          ),
          listener: NativeAdListener(
            onAdLoaded: (Ad ad) {
              print('$BannerAd loaded.');
              bannerAdIsLoaded.value = true;
            },
            onAdFailedToLoad: (Ad ad, LoadAdError error) {
              print('$BannerAd failedToLoad: $error');
              ad.dispose();
            },
            onAdOpened: (Ad ad) => print('$BannerAd onAdOpened.'),
            onAdClosed: (Ad ad) => print('$BannerAd onAdClosed.'),
          ),
          request: const AdRequest(),
        )..load();

        return () => bannerAd.value!.dispose();
      },
      [],
    );

    // if we have an ad to show -> show it
    if (bannerAdIsLoaded.value && bannerAd.value != null) {
      return SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: const BoxConstraints(
              minWidth: 300,
              minHeight: 350,
              maxHeight: 800,
              maxWidth: 450,
            ),
            child: AdWidget(ad: bannerAd.value!),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    return const SizedBox();
  }
}
```

I really need to be able to pass an adUnitId and the native ad to adapt natively to the height of it.

I have found multiple issues, but no solution yet.
For example: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter/issues/442

Did anyone figure this out?